# invalid identifier error while using NVL in EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SELECT

Tags: oracle

```
create or replace PROCEDURE P_STAGE_LOAD(
    in_S IN VARCHAR2,
    in_D     IN VARCHAR2,
    in_T   IN VARCHAR2)
IS
 v_ERRM VARCHAR2(32000);
BEGIN
  IF in_TBL_NAME ='TRAN_CUSTOMER' THEN
    EXECUTE immediate 'INSERT INTO  TRAN_CUSTOMER 
      (CUSTOMER_ID,AUTH_ID,OTHER_ID,TRAN_TYPE,AUDIT_TS)    
      SELECT CUSTOMER_ID,AUTH_ID,OTHER_ID,NVL(TRAN_TYPE,'PRIMARY'),
         SYSDATE 
    FROM '||in_S||'.'||in_T||'@'||in_D;
    EXECUTE immediate 'COMMIT';
```

This gives error as `Invalid Identifier` in run time. However the SELECT query runs fine alone. 
I want to handle `NULL` of `TRAN_TYPE`, and decode to get as `PRIMARY` when `NULL`. 
The target table `TRAN_CUSTOMER` has this as `NOT NULL` Column.

Is there anything missing?

Comment: Where is `END IF` and `END` part? Also which line the error is coming from and what is the exact error with error code.

Comment: its in this line SELECT CUSTOMER_ID,AUTH_ID,OTHER_ID,NVL(TRAN_TYPE,'PRIMARY'),

Comment: What happens if you remove `nvl` and just use `tran_type`?

Comment: Instead of execute immediate, write out the SQL to a variable and then `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` the variable so you can [debug](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TTPLP/d_output.htm#TTPLP71197) the SQL... I think you'll find a problem with how 'PRIMARY' is being added.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use two single quotes for `PRIMARY` as first single quote is ending the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` string.

Use something like below in that line.

```
EXECUTE immediate 'INSERT INTO  TRAN_CUSTOMER 
      (CUSTOMER_ID,AUTH_ID,OTHER_ID,TRAN_TYPE,AUDIT_TS)    
      SELECT CUSTOMER_ID,AUTH_ID,OTHER_ID,NVL(TRAN_TYPE,''PRIMARY''),
         SYSDATE 
    FROM '||in_S||'.'||in_T||'@'||in_D;
```

Comment: above one i tried using 2 single quotes and ended it after FROM . The errors